# Remove ndf file from primary

Tags: sql-server, database

here's my situation, I have two files in the primary file group for a database name SELLOUT_DWH:

[image: Image:]

I want to remove the file "Rows.ndf", but I haven't been able to, I tried DBCC SHRINKFILE with EMPTYFILE option but it says: "Cannot move all contents of file "ROWS" to other places to complete the emptyfile operation". ¿Is there any option to delete this file?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: You might require to add .ndf file to different filegroup and create/alter tables to point that filegroup.

Comment: ¿Is there any other way without moving the objects to the other filegroup?